# Cannot open Workflows from Item after deleting workflows via Powershell

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I did the following:

```
$oldWorkflow="MyOldWorkflow";
$oldAssoc=$list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName($oldWorkflow,"en-US");
$list.RemoveWorkflowAssociation($oldAssoc);
```

After that I can see that the workflow does not exist anymore. But on each Item that had the workflow before I receive an error when trying to display the workflows:

```
Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentException: Column 'Reservat' doesn't exist
```

I never had a column with that name. After adding that column manually to the list, the error messages changed to:

```
Application error when access /_layouts/15/Workflow.aspx, Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any chance to solve this mess? (The old workflow does NOT exist anymore as WSP)

UPDATE:
I can still find the workflows using Powershell:

```
     foreach ($wf in $item.Workflows) 
  if ($wf.ParentAssociation.Name -eq $oldWorkflow) 
                ...
```

But in the same time `$list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName` does NOT return the workflow

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. Note for all those who came here by google: **This is not a good practice for removing workflows**, but only a solution if you already messed up your workflows in SharePoint. (like me)

```
   $oldWorkflow="MyOldWorkflow";
        foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
                foreach ($wf in $item.Workflows) {
                    if ($wf.ParentAssociation.Name -eq $oldWorkflow)  {
                        Write-Host ("[{0}] Workflow '{1}' will be removed" -f $item.Title, $wf.ParentAssociation.Name);                            
                        $itemsToAdd.Add($wf);
                }
            }
        }
        ForEach($item in $itemsToAdd) {
            $man.RemoveWorkflowFromListItem($item);  
        }
```